# maven attach-artifact - keep the original name

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am using `build-helper-maven-plugin` with `attach-artifact` goal to add a custom jar file to Nexus, next to the ear file. After build is finished the jar file is there but instead of keeping it's original name it's renamed to `<project_name>-ear-<version>-<timestamp>.jar`. Is there anything I can do to keep it's original name, i.e. configure Maven to keep the name?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>../xxx/src/main/resources/lib/DbSynchronizer.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No ... the Maven repository format uses the coordinates to assemble predictable file names ensuring that they can be downloaded reliably using the Maven repository format. If you need a different filename.. rename the file after downloading it.